# Why doesn't a variable get passed into a new class

Tags: python, python-3.x

**The code you find below has been shortened down so that you don't have to read through my whole code. I have provided bits of the code I feel are needed to be able to solve my problem.**

So here is one of my classes:

```
class Terminal(Pane):

    def setText(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.text_changed = True
        mac = "bobbyli"
        Application.monitorInput(mac)
```

Here is the other class:

```
class Application(Terminal):

    def monitorInput(self, text):

            clock = pygame.time.Clock()

            RUNNING = True
            while RUNNING:

                for event in pygame.event.get():

                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        RUNNING = False
                        break

                    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                            self.show_keyboard = not self.show_keyboard
                            self.show_panes = not self.show_panes

                    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:

                        #took away bits you didn't need

                        elif textSelected == "OK":
                            with open("setPhrases.txt", 'r') as infile:
                                data = infile.read()
                                print(data)
                            print("Bob")
                            print(text)
                            print("Bob")

                            self.deletePanes()
                            self.createPhrases()



                        # --- draws terminal to reflect the additions ---
                        if self.show_terminal:
                            self.terminal.draw()

            self.close()
```

Then this is how I run the code:

```
myApp = Application()

#start the monitoring of events on screen
myApp.monitorInput('')
```

So my problem is that whenever I try to pass `mac` through into `Application`, and try to print it from this line of the code, I end up printing `Bob\n (empty space)\n Bob`:

```
elif textSelected == "OK":
    with open("setPhrases.txt", 'r') as infile:
        data = infile.read()
        print(data)
    print("Bob")
    print(text)
    print("Bob")

    self.deletePanes()
    self.createPhrases()
```

Why is it passing nothing into `text`. What am I doing wrong? Please help me fix the problem. I honestly have no clue on what I am doing wrong. I had done this previously in another part of my code and it worked fine but I am sure I must be doing something wrong/different compared to that part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Once you call `myApp.monitorInput('')`, the local variable `text` of the method `Application.monitorInput` is set to `''` and will never change. Subsequent calls to `monitorInput` just runs anew the same function (with different locals on a different frame), but if the first is still running (due to the loop), then inside the first method `text` is still `''`.

By the way `Application.monitorInput(mac)` should raise an error, as it misses one positional argument (as you run it on the class and not on an instance and hence `self` is not bound).

To illustrate this:

```
class Application:
    def monitorInput(self, text):
        print ('here be dragons')

myApp = Application()
myApp.monitorInput ('bobby')
Application.monitorInput ('bobby') #exception here
```

Raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./amt.py", line 9, in <module>
    Application.monitorInput ('bobby')
TypeError: monitorInput() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'
```